# SSDT installed in VS 2012, grayed out in SSMS 2012

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, ssms-2012

Before I start, I have Googled the hell out of this issue to no avail and the tech support at my office is equally stumped (shocking).

I installed SQL Server Data Tools for Visual Studio 2012 from MSDN. It is currently working in Visual Studio 2012. I can create Integration Services projects without a problem - which is awesome.

However, when I open SQL Server Management Studio 2012, the options for Analysis Services, Integration Services, and Reporting Services are all grayed out. I am 90% sure I'm running Enterprise SSMS (please correct me if I'm wrong based on the "About" info below).

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      11.0.2100.60
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML                     3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                     9.11.9600.17420
Microsoft .NET Framework                        4.0.30319.18444
Operating System                        6.1.7601
```

So my question is... how do I connect to these services in SSMS?

Answer (score 0):

I know these "special services" require "special access rights granted by your DBA.  After I got rights to see Integration Services, a "Integration Services Catalog" folder showed up under my server in the Object Explorer.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Patrick. I have full DBOwner permissions on our servers so that shouldn't be an issue. It seems to be SSMS on my local PC that is creating the problem.

Comment: Hmm, I  don't know how a client issue could cause this.